# limit of $\sum_{j=n}^{4n}\binom{4n}j(1/4)^j(3/4)^{4n-j}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find out the value of the limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=n}^{4n} \dbinom{4n}{j} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^j \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{4n-j}$$

I am not getting any hint:
please give me hint so that i can solve this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the Law of Large numbers?

Answer (score 3):

**Completely revised to match the corrected question.**

Here’s a heuristic argument to point you in the right direction. Consider an experiment with a probability of success of $\frac14$, e.g., tossing two fair coins and getting heads on both. Repeat the experiment $4n$ times, and let the random variable $X_n$ be the number of successes. Then $\Bbb E(X_n)=n$, and

$$\Bbb P[X_n\ge n]=\sum_{j=n}^{4n}\binom{4n}j\left(\frac14\right)^j\left(\frac34\right)^{4n-j}$$

is the probability of getting at least $n$ successes. Clearly

$$\Bbb P[X_n=n]=\binom{4n}n\left(\frac14\right)^n\left(\frac34\right)^{3n}=\binom{4n}n\cdot\frac{3^{3n}}{4^{4n}}\;;$$

apply [Stirling’s approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to the binomial coefficient to show that $\Bbb P[X_n=n]\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Finally, for large $n$ this binomial distribution is [approximately a normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) with mean $n$ and hence approximately symmetric about $n$, so for large $n$ we have

$$\Bbb P[X_n<n]\approx\Bbb P[X_n>n]\;,$$

and hence $\Bbb P[X_n\ge n]$ must approach what as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: thank you for your hint,but i forgot to put (4n,j) in the problem.

Comment: thank you very much now i got the answer .

Comment: @user157012: You’re very welcome.